# child process acts stange premiere pro cep on m1

Tags: node.js, sdk, adobe, child-process, extendscript

I created a cep to call an executable Python script that I compiled
everything works fine I can run the executable file and get buffer data
however, when I added a media path, I got back an empty buffer!!

this happened just on (M1 Macos Monterey) buffer is empty
only when I add the media path but I can try to run the file,
it works also when tried to run on nodejs outside the cep framework, and it works fine on the same machine

```
const { execFile, spawn } = require('child_process');
const media = '/Users/Documents/example.mp4';
// this is my compiled executable python script 
const pymain = '/Users/Documents/__main__/__main__' ; 

var argarray = [media, '--info'];
const child = spawn(pymain, argarray);

var buffy='' ; 

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

    buffy += data.toString() ; 

});

child.on('close', function (exitcode) {
    alert(buffy);
});

process.on('exit', function () {
    child.kill()
})
```

on my old laptop, it works fine
MacBook bro 2018 Macos Venture it works fine, and I get data inside the buffer (buffy)

Comment: Some secutiry mess from Adobe + Apple? I'd try to test with a full (no `~`) path to some user's folder. Something like `/Users/your_name/Documents/test_folder`. Just to be sure.

Comment: yeah it looks like security issue but why it's working when I try to test the executable like like reading the help 
when I send the video file for processing it does not work !!
and this is just on m1 ?!!

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area. I'd suggest that the there are different 'actors' with different rights. You as a user have the access, Python has the access, but some of Adobe's applications that runs the script at some point has no access. It's weird if it has something to do with the chip M1. But if there are two versions of macOS (M1/x86) they can have different set of glitches. And probably the above mentioned some Adobe's app runs on M1 via some emulator, it can get additional fancy troubles.